# Get original values with Average from T-SQL Pivot using CTE

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to get the results I need from a CTE into a Pivot. I have a table that has the following fields:

```
ReadingDescription Varchar(50)
ReadingDate datetime
ReadingValue int
```

Data would look like this:

```
MinDemand  1-1-2012  250
MaxDemand  1-1-2012  300
MinDemand  1-2-2012  260
MaxDemand  1-2-2012  310
MinDemand  1-3-2012  250
MaxDemand  1-3-2012  300
MinDemand  1-4-2012  260
MaxDemand  1-4-2012  310
```

I need an output that would look like this:

```
ReadingDate  MinDemand   MaxDemand    AvgDemand
1-1-2012     250           300           275
1-2-2012     260           310           285
1-2-2012     250           300           275
1-2-2012     260           310           285
```

I have been researching and I think I'm close but can't get past the CTE part. Here is what I have so far:

```
with cte as (

SELECT 

  CONVERT(DATE,h.ReadingDate,1) as ReadingDate,
  left(ReadingDescription,11) as Reading,
  h.ReadingValue
FROM


FAC_WeeklyReadings  wr  
JOIN
FAC_WeeklyReadingsHistory h ON  h.WeeklyReadingID =  wr.WeeklyReadingID                 

where
wr.WeeklyReadingID in (149,150)
AND
h.ReadingDate BETWEEN '1-1-2012' AND '12-31-2012'
)

pivot(
--I have tried several things here but have not been successful
--
) p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why pivot ? isnt it easier to just goup by ?

```
select ReadingDate, min(ReadingValue), max(ReadingValue),  avg(ReadingValue)
from FAC_WeeklyReadings  wr  JOIN  FAC_WeeklyReadingsHistory h 
   ON  h.WeeklyReadingID =  wr.WeeklyReadingID                 
where wr.WeeklyReadingID in (149,150)
   AND h.ReadingDate BETWEEN '1-1-2012' AND '12-31-2012'
group by h.ReadingDate
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with cte as (

SELECT 

  CONVERT(DATE,h.ReadingDate,1) as ReadingDate,
  left(ReadingDescription,11) as Reading,
  h.ReadingValue
FROM


FAC_WeeklyReadings  wr  
JOIN
FAC_WeeklyReadingsHistory h ON  h.WeeklyReadingID =  wr.WeeklyReadingID                 

where
wr.WeeklyReadingID in (149,150)
AND
h.ReadingDate BETWEEN '1-1-2012' AND '12-31-2012'
)

SELECT *, (MinDemand+MaxDemand)/2 AvgDemand
FROM CTE T
PIVOT(MIN(ReadingValue) FOR Reading IN ([MinDemand],[MaxDemand])) AS PT
```

Comment: I tried your solution but got back all NULL values. The solution by WKordos worked great although I would like to have a better understanding of how to use Pivot so I'll keep plugging away at this. Thanks for your help.